# Sencha Cmd Error: Build Failed

Tags: extjs

After running sencha generated app Practise '../www/Practise' it showed some errors. Here the error message:

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time :4 seconds
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
```

Comment: Gonna need a larger error stack than that in order for us to help you...

Comment: If you generated your app with sencha cmd but you build is failing this is most likely because you are missing a dependency in one or more of your files somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the same issue you were having but this is why I got that error:

1. I tried to generate the app unsuccessfully

   - This created a directory for my app and put some files in it but the app was incomplete
2. I fixed the original issue and ran the
   command again.

   - I got the error you were receiving.

This was because the folder in www/*yourproject* already existed. I deleted this folder and ran the command successfully.

Hope this helps!!